# In WPF, access a control that is instantiated in a XAML file from a separate Class?

Tags: c#, wpf

We have a class in our WPF project that we want to access a control that is put into a XAML file.  I have put my code below and file structure to help with my question.

**Folder Structure:**
Navigation Directors\ FullKioskDirector.cs

MasterTemplates \ SellAllKioskMaster.xaml

Views \ Pages \ PageTemplates \ PageAttractScreen.xaml

We want 'FullKioskDirector.cs' to access the visibility of 'PageAttractScreen.xaml'. The 'SellAllKioskMaster.xaml' is referencing the 'PageAttractScreen.xaml' in its XAML.

Here is our code below.

**SellAllKioskMaster.xaml**

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:UserControls="clr-namespace:Kiosk.Views.Pages.UserControls" xmlns:PageTemplates="clr-namespace:Kiosk.Views.Pages.PageTemplates" x:Class="Kiosk.MasterTemplates.MyContainer" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="1049" d:DesignWidth="1912" Background="White">
  <Grid>
    <!--I need to access the visibility of these elements from the 'FullKioskDirector.cs'-->
     <PageTemplates:PageAttractScreen x:Name="pageAttract" Margin="0,100"/>
     <PageTemplates:PageWelcomeScreen x:Name="pageWelcome" Margin="0,100"/>
    <PageTemplates:PageProductsScreen x:Name="pageProducts" Margin="0,100"/>
   </Grid>
 </UserControl>
```

**FullKioskDirector.cs**

```
 using System;
 using System.Windows;
 using System.Windows.Controls;
 using Kiosk.Common.Common.Contracts;
 using Kiosk.Views.Pages.UserControls;

 namespace Kiosk.Directors
 {
     public class FullKioskDirector : IPageNavigation
     {
         public FullKioskDirector()
         {
         /*
        Want to control visibility of my controls that are placed and 
       x:Named in the SellAllKioskMaster.xaml
         */
         }
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better if you do it in an `MVVM` approach, rather than doing everything from code behind.

Nevertheless, wherever you are creating `FullKioskDirector`, just pass in `pageAttract` to the constructor.

Assuming you create the `FullKioskDirector` at `UserControl`'s constructor

```
public UserControl()
{
  var fullKioskDirector = new FullKioskDirector(pageAttract);
}
```

Then you can use it like this

```
public FullKioskDirector(PageAttractScreen pageAttract)
{
   pageAttract.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: @III, I made some edits to my question with a bit more information. I am actually trying to control visibility of multiple items within the FullKIoskDirector.  I also made the naming the actual naming of my classes and XAML files.  Can you point me in the correct direction based on my edits?

Comment: @ClosDesign I edited where you can access the visibility. I don't know how you want to control the visibility but that should give you an idea how to control the visibilities of those controls.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Publish / Subscribe pattern.

Example: MessageBus / EventAggregator

This is my tool of choice when dealing with dependency challenges.

Essentially, you just post a message for subscribers to react to.
In this case your subscriber will then post a response in the form of a control.

You can leverage [Bizmonger.Patterns](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bizmonger.Patterns/1.0.0) to get the MessageBus.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx